# VBA copying all the Excel files in a folder to a single file causes runtime error

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use VBA to open all the excel files in a directory (in this case c:\temp) and put all the files datasheets in one large file.  Each new sheet is named with the filename plus the name of the sheet on the original document.  The code that I have copies the first file's first sheet and even names it correctly, but then fails with a Run-time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error on the second sheet when I try to set the name.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix.

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String

' Create a new workbook
Set FileWorkbook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

' folder path to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\Temp\"

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""

    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sheetIndex As Integer
    sheetIndex = 1

    Windows(WorkBk.Name).Activate

    For Each currentSheet In WorkBk.Worksheets
        currentSheet.Select
        currentSheet.Copy Before:=Workbooks(FileWorkbook.Name).Sheets(sheetIndex)
        FileWorkbook.Sheets(sheetIndex).Name = FileName & "-" & currentSheet.Name
        sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1
    Next currentSheet

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you debug on the error and check what values are populating the sheet name ie make sure it doesn't have any of these \ / * [ ] : ? characters or that its not longer than 31 characters. Otherwise add watches to each part of the line to see which one is erroring out. Hope this helps.

Comment: Surely you need to create the worksheet before you can name it, workbooks don't contain infinite sheets.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/456-combine-multiple-workbooks.html

Comment: @NickA I would considering copying the sheet to be creating it. Maybe something to do with the `sheetIndex`? Stepping through here and checking the values I think is the best stategy to see what is going on.

Comment: I had a similar problem with sheet name length and characters at work once, my solution was to initially remove special characters then reduce the name to a max of 31 and then cycle through the sheets testing the name and if it exists to alter the new sheet name (in my case I shortened it).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments.  The answer below fixed the code and works great.  The only thing I had to add was a check for hidden sheets and to move the activate of the source sheet inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
FileWorkbook.Sheets(sheetIndex).Name = FileName & "-" & currentSheet.Name
```

with (I separated it out for readability)

```
sWSName = FileName & "-" & currentSheet.Name
sWSName = NameTest(sWSName)
sWSName = TestDup(sWSName)
FileWorkbook.Sheets(sheetIndex).Name = sWSName
```

You will need to define the sWSName.

Below are the modified functions I have previously used.

```
Function NameTest(sName As String) As String
  NameTest = sName
  aSpecChars = Array("\", "/", "*", "[", "]", ":", "?")
  For Each c In aSpecChars
    NameTest = Replace(NameTest, c, "")
  Next c

  If Len(sName) > 31 Then NameTest = Left(sName, 31)

End Function

Function TestDup(sWSName As String) As String
  TestDup = sWSName
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name
    If sWSName = ws.Name Then TestDup = TestDup(Left(sWSName, Len(sWSName) - 1))
  Next ws
End Function
```

*If posting this code (or to this extent) is out of line please let me know as I am still coming to terms with the level of effort require versus reasonable response.*

Comment: Works great!  Thanks so much for the help